# Polymer properties from chrome console

Tags: polymer, google-chrome-console

This is a very newbie question, but how can I reference a polymer property from Chrome's console? I know I can output (console.log) from javascript in my application with a reference to **this.myProperty**, but how do I get a reference to it straight from the console?

Answer (score 2):

You get a reference to the element by some method, I use `querySelector` so if you have a `paper-input` with the class `username-input` you can do something like this

```
document.querySelector('paper-input.username-input').myProperty
```

and that would be the same as doing a `this.myProperty` from inside the element.

Answer (score 0):

During development *only* I create a property on `window` that references my 
element.

```
Polymer({
  is: 'nav-bar',

  properties: {
    foo: {
      type: String,
      value: 'foo'
    }
  },

  attached: function() {
    // @TODO remove before merge.
    window.navBar = this
  }
})
```

And in your console:

```
// log property
navBar.foo

// call methods
navbar.doSomething()
```

to check properties or call methods on my element.

Granted, this pollutes the global scope but I do this only during development.
You can also select the element via `querySelector('nav-bar')` but it's tedious
to do so and you lose console autocompletion. Time is money.